# Shubox is not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using [Shubox](https://shubox.io/) to upload and transform images in my rails app. I just completed the setup, but am running into the following error when I load my image form:

[image]

Here's my setup:

**Install**

```
npm install shubox
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<script src="shubox.umd.js"></script>
```

**application.js**

```
import Shubox from 'shubox'
```

posts/new.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  new Shubox("#drag-drop-here", { key: "<%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:shubox, :key) %>" });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use outof webpack you must be export shubox. You can must this;

Change file content of config/webpack/environment.js:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Shubox: 'shubox/src/shubox' # Whats the path
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

another way add this line to application.js

```
window.Shubox = Shubox
```

Answer (score 0):

So there's a mix of approaches that are causing this to not be found/work -- NPM and straight up script tag.

If you want to do it the old school way: https://github.com/shuboxio/shubox.js#the--old-school--script-embed

```sh
curl -L https://unpkg.com/shubox -o public/shubox.js
```

and then you'll be able to reference that file in your views as `<script src="shubox.js"></script>`

The mix here is that you're doing both the new-school/modern NPM route, and the old school script tag way.